# How to Display No Data for Export Alert when there is no data found Angular 6 kendo-excelexport Component

Tags: angular, angular6, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

Below is the code :i used angular 6 kendo-excelexport ^4.5.0 version component.

```
<kendo-excelexport [data]="excelDataToExport" [collapsible]="true" fileName="Sample.xlsx" #excelexport>
                <kendo-excelexport-column field="taxMonth" title="Month" [width]="200">
                </kendo-excelexport-column>
                <kendo-excelexport-column field="clientName" title="Client Name" [width]="200">
                </kendo-excelexport-column>
                <kendo-excelexport-column field="alertType" title="Alert Type" [width]="200">

                <kendo-excelexport-column field="Description" title="Description" [width]="200">
                </kendo-excelexport-column>

</kendo-excelexport>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the length of `excelDataToExport` if it is an array. If the length is greater than 0, download the excel sheet else show an alert.

To achieve this, use conditional expression on the `click` event of the export button.

Please find the working example: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yymmxg-jrxpmw)

In the example comment/uncomment the data in product.ts file to see the no data alert / download excel respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Main idea is to test for the data: if it's present, you can display the table. If it is null, you can display a message. If you bind it in the template, change detection takes care of updating the DOM for you if the data changes after the component is loaded:

```
<div *ngIf="excelDataToExport">...table code here ....</div>

<div *ngIf="!excelDataToExport">No data to export present</div>
```

To improve this code even further, you can use templates to avoid using two `ngIf`-s:
...
and define a template:

```
<ng-template #noDataLabel>No data to export present</ng-template>
```

It will replace the the div's content. Read more about this [in the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf).

Answer (score 2):

You can use trigger excel export action manually as follows:

[Stackblitz Demo](https://grid-excel-export-kendo.stackblitz.io)

In that you can add your required functionality in function named ***onExcelExport***